# Scrapy response is a different language from request and resposne url

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape search results from this page

[http://eur-lex.europa.eu/search.html?qid=1437402891621&DB_TYPE_OF_ACT=advGeneral&CASE_LAW_SUMMARY=false&DTS_DOM=EU_LAW&typeOfActStatus=ADV_GENERAL&type=advanced&lang=fr&SUBDOM_INIT=EU_CASE_LAW&DTS_SUBDOM=EU_CASE_LAW](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/search.html?qid=1437402891621&DB_TYPE_OF_ACT=advGeneral&CASE_LAW_SUMMARY=false&DTS_DOM=EU_LAW&typeOfActStatus=ADV_GENERAL&type=advanced&lang=en&SUBDOM_INIT=EU_CASE_LAW&DTS_SUBDOM=EU_CASE_LAW)

The language according to the url is french, and that is what I see in the scrapy shell, following 'crawled (200) '

If I try response.url I also get a url with lang=fr.

Viewing the page in a browser shows me french results.

However, the body of the response is English.

I've tried disabling cookies in my scrapy settings.py file.
I've also set the DEFAULT_REQUEST HEADERS to 'Accept-Language': 'fr'.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can choose the language in the upper right corner and then there's another parameter added to the url '&locale=fr'. Maybe you can add this parameter to your start_url!?

Comment: That seems to have solved it! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome :-) I posted my comment as an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the upper right corner of the webpage there's a drop down field to choose the language of the website. Selecting `french` there will add another parameter to the url: `&locale=fr`.

So - add that parameter to your `start_url`.